# How to conditionally style only certain screen widths and fallback to defaults for other screen widths?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following

```
<TableCell sx={{ borderBottom: { xs: 0, lg: 1 } }}>
    <Typography variant="body2">{account.name} ({account.currency})</Typography>
</TableCell>
```

This ends up overriding the following (default)

```
/*border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);*/
```

with

```
border-bottom: 1px solid;
```

on large screens. I don't want to specify borderBottomColor, instead I just want to mention in sx itself to default it back on lg screens. Is that possible, if so how?

Not much info about it in the documentation https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/

Answer (score 0):

The [breakpoints object](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/usage/#responsive-values) syntax only applies going "up" (larger) per the docs:

> **Breakpoints as an object**
>
> The first option for breakpoints is to
> define them as an object, using the breakpoint values as keys. *Note
> that each property for a given breakpoint also applies to all larger
> breakpoints in the set. For example, `width: { lg: 100 }` is equivalent
> to `theme.breakpoints.up('lg')`*.

And unfortunately the [border utilities API](https://mui.com/system/borders/#api) does not cover extended border CSS longhand like [`borderBottomWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom-width) (as a workaround).

Since you're trying to define styles going "down" (smaller), you may need to define your own behavior, using the [theme breakpoints helper functions](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries), in the `sx` prop. For example:

```
<TableCell
  sx={(theme) => ({
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      borderBottom: "none"
    }
  })}
>
  My cell title
</TableCell>
```

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-breakpoints-in-sx-dz2whq?file=/demo.tsx